# sqlite и telebot

Tags: python, sqlite

Я делаю телеграмм бот в питоне. И как мне с питона добавить видео и фото в sqlite, и после нажатия на кнопку, телеграмм бот должен отправить видео или фото с базу данных пользователю. Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса). чтобы вам было понятней - первый из вопросов: «как добавить видео и фото в базу данных?». на него, кстати, самый банальный ответ: «никак». потому что не надо этого делать. блобы надо хранить в файловой системе, а в базе данных - только текст, например, пути к блобам.

Comment: Добавлять file_id в БД и никак иначе